# Can I implement admob for a app running in iPhone OS 4?

Tags: iphone, banner, ipad

I am creating an universal app. The app should be able to run properly in iPad, iPhone 4.0 OS and also in iPhone OS with versions more than 3.0. I want to implement a banner in my application.

In my case using iAd or AdMob should I create the banner. Since I am creating universal app I don't know the proper way of approaching this. Is there any alternate to create the banner view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdMob as an ad provider in iOS4 without problem.

If you wish to use iAds and AdMob I suggest taking a look at the AdWhirl solution.

If I understand you correctly, you will always need to create some kind of view where your ad will be shown. Check in the AdWhirl FAQ and full instructions and some demo code are included there.

I don't quite follow what you mean by creating the banner?